# LDAP create members relations for users and groups

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I don't have an access to LDAP server, instead I've a DB with tables for Users and Groups.

Now I want to build a table with members relationship, in other words I would like to build a table where each entry is a relation between single User and single Group.

I do have for each Group the attribute "member" where the value is a list of direct members DNs. So theoretically I can iterate for each DN in the "member" for each Group and check in table of Users if this is a valid user DN, if yes add it to the members table. The problem is with recursive members (User A is member of Group X which is member of Group Y, so User A is also a member of Group Y).

What will be the best way to find all recursive members?
Is it possible to have a circular recursive?